# Whitelisting the formatting rules

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I work for a data-security company and I am trying to whitelist certain rules on our server regarding the CF7 forms on our website, in order to eliminate as many attack options as possible.
I searched high and low an could not find the format rules for certain elements in the form.
When I inspect the element of the forms I get the following list (I removed the ones that don't need addressing):

```
_wpcf7:1562
_wpcf7_version:4.1.2
_wpcf7_locale:en_US
_wpcf7_unit_tag:wpcf7-f1562-o2
_wpnonce:2257b0dde3
_wpcf7_is_ajax_call:1
```

What I need is to know exactly what the value of every one of these elements can accept. For example - `_wpcf7_version` is it always only numbers and punctuation marks?
Or `_wpcf7_unit_tag` is it always only lowercase letters, numbers and dashes?
I'll wright the list and my assumptions regarding the possible values and I simply need to know if this is ALWAYS the case or can be something else:

`_wpcf7` digits only;
`_wpcf7_version`: digits and periods only;

`_wpcf7_locale`: uppercase, lowercase and underscore;

`_wpcf7_unit_tag`: lowercase letters, numbers and dashes;
`_wpnonce`:
   digits and lowercase leters only; `_wpcf7_is_ajax_call`: digits only.

Thanks!!
Amos

P.S - apologies for the formatting of this message. For some reason the text doesn't always go down a line when I press enter and after struggling with it for a while I decided you'd forgive me :)

Comment: wow... 4 days.. :\  
I guess I'm not getting an answer for this..

Comment: The variables are set in the `form_hidden_fields()` function in `wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php`. Maybe you can look here.